# Events overlapping times validation in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need help, I have a stored procedure for inserting an event that is displayed in a calendar, what I intend to do is validate if I have an event in ID_SALA 2 or ID_SALA 3 on the same date should not have the same start and end times.

My ID_SALA has only has 2 rows:

```
ID_SALA | Name
 2      | AUDITORIO
 3      | SALA VIRTUAL
```

My format date is: `YYYY/MM/DD`

My begin and end parameters are:

```
  @START_TIME NVARCHAR(5) i insert this 11:00
  @END_TIME NVARCHAR(5)   i insert this 12:00
```

Here is an image of the event calendar

[image: My event calendar]

```
@DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(500),
@ID_SALA INT,
@ID_TIPO_SOLICITANTE INT,
@DATE SMALLDATETIME,
@START_TIME NVARCHAR(5),
@END_TIME NVARCHAR(5),
@ID_PRESTATARIO INT,
@ID_USUARIO INT,
@SOLICITANTE NVARCHAR(150),
@AUTORIZACION INT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ID_PERIODO INT

SELECT @ID_PERIODO = ID_PERIODO FROM CAT_PERIODOS WHERE ACTIVO = 1


INSERT INTO PRESTAMO_SALA
    (DESCRIPCION, ID_SALA, ID_TIPO_SOLICITANTE, FECHA_PRESTAMO, HORA_INICIO, HORA_FIN, ID_PRESTATARIO, 

ID_USUARIO, ID_PERIODO, FECHA_REG, SOLICITANTE, ID_AUTORIZACION)
VALUES
    (@DESCRIPCION, @ID_SALA, @ID_TIPO_SOLICITANTE, @DATE, @START_TIME, @END_TIME, @ID_PRESTATARIO, @ID_USUARIO, 

@ID_PERIODO, GETDATE(), @SOLICITANTE, @AUTORIZACION)

SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID_PRESTAMO_SALA
```

Sorry for my English

Comment: Are you trying to check if two events in the same location have overlapping time?

Comment: that's what I try to do

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117962/simplest-efficient-way-to-find-rows-with-time-interval-overlaps-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check at the top of the stored procedure to see if there is an event in that location that overlaps the time with the new event.

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM PRESTAMO_SALA PS
  WHERE PS.START_TIME <= @END_TIME 
      AND PS.END_TIME >= @START_TIME 
      AND PS.[DATE] = @DATE
      AND PS.ID_SALA = @ID_SALA 
      )

    ... RAISE ERROR ...
```