# How to write a query to return all records that fall between the date range

Tags: sql, oracle

From the below table, I need to fetch all the records that fall under the range.

Datatypes are Date for StartDate and Enddate.

**For example 1**: if the variable Start date  is 2021-12-30 and variable end date is 2022-09-25 then I need below two records since 2021-12-30.

Table:

```
Absence   StartDate   EndDate
30069   23-DEC-21   23-DEC-21
30112   29-DEC-21   31-DEC-21
129228  23-SEP-22   23-SEP-22
24042   08-OCT-21   08-OCT-21
24043   29-NOV-21   29-NOV-21
```

Expected Records:

```
30112   29-DEC-21   31-DEC-21
129228  23-SEP-22   23-SEP-22
```

**For example 2**: if the variable Start date  is 2021-10-07 and variable end date is 2022-11-30 then I need below two records

```
24042   08-OCT-21   08-OCT-21
24043   29-NOV-21   29-NOV-21
```

Answers to Open Questions:

1. Updated Title
2. Column Datatypes are VARCHAR2 for Absence and rest are DATE and there will be no null values
3. Here variable startDate and EndDate is bind variable which will be passed in Runtime. We need to fetch all the absences that falls under startDate and EndDate range. So for example 1, since 30-DEC-21 is bind variable startDate that falls between the range where absence is 30112. We need to fetch that records. Consider the employee being on leave for a time period and if bind var startDate falls under that range then we need to consider that records in output as well since employee was on leave.

Comment: "I need" is no question. Please explain what you have tried, what didn't work as expected, why it didn't work and what exactly you want to know.

Comment: In 1st example, why is 30112 in result set? Its start date is 29-DEC-2021, while *variable* (parameter?) start date is 30-DEC-2021 which is **after** 29-DEC-2021. So - why should that record be returned? Which **rules** have to be followed?

Comment: You ask for the same question again: [Query to find the records between the start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75600375/query-to-find-the-records-between-the-start-date-and-end-date). Please clarify the difference between the previous question (which has 4 answers) and this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a simple and efficient way to find rows with time-interval overlaps in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117962/what-is-a-simple-and-efficient-way-to-find-rows-with-time-interval-overlaps-in-s)

Comment: When a newbie user asks a not unreasonable question (it has sample data and expected result for example) should we be quick to close?

Comment: The question doen't have a line of code or a description of the *issue* - just the requirement. Is it a quiz? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2778710) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and all 4 answers on the previous exactly the same questions (which has no any feedback on all 4 answers).

Answer (score 1):

It may be counter-intuitive, but if you compare the start_date to the range_end and compare end_date to range_start it actually gets easier.

```
select *
from yourtable
where StartDate <= range_end
and EndDate >= range_start
```

1. nothing that starts after the range_end is included
2. nothing that finishes before the range_start is include
3. data that spans the range is included
4. data the starts/end within the range is included

---

```
        RangeStart        RangeEnd            
————————————|————————————————|———————————> t
  S     E   |                |             |  EndDate is not > range_start
        S   |           E    |             |  StartDate < range_end & EndDate > range_start
            |     S     E    |             |  StartDate < range_end & EndDate > range_start
            |     S          |    E        |  StartDate < range_end & EndDate > range_start
        S   |                |    E        |  StartDate < range_end & EndDate > range_start
            |                |    S    E   | StartDate is not < range_end
```

NB: using = in the query may depend on the data itself e.g. a start point within a day and the end point within a day can be a valid work duration (for example).

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac411c/1

```
Absence StartDate               EndDate
30112   2021-12-29T00:00:00Z    2021-12-31T00:00:00Z
129228  2022-09-23T00:00:00Z    2022-09-23T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: Both conditions should have the same comparison (either `<=` or `<` depending on interval definition) because they are semantically interchangeable: you may replace one interval with another and should have the same result

Comment: @astentx If the dates have a non-midnight time component and you want the full day for the final day then you may want different comparisons (if you are passing midnight dates for the range bounds). I.e. `WHERE start_date < range_end + 1 AND end_date >= range_start`