# Transform a table based on date overlap

Tags: sql, mysql, date, overlap, gaps-and-islands

## Problem statement

Hi there, I'm a beginner SQL user. I have an access to a database for research, there's one table of interest structured as follow:

| `id` | `date` | `use` | `item` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | 90 | A |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 | 10 | B |
| 1 | 2023-03-15 | 15 | C |
| 2 | 2023-02-05 | 10 | B |
| 2 | 2023-02-13 | 30 | A |

This is a table of `item` acquisition `date` done by a personnel `id`. I want to transform this table based on the overlap of `date` for each personnel `id`, but not quite sure of how to achieve that.

## Desired output

I imagine the resulting table would be as follow:

| `id` | `start` | `end` | `item` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 29 | A |
| 1 | 30 | 39 | A, B |
| 1 | 40 | 43 | A |
| 1 | 44 | 58 | A, C |
| 1 | 59 | 90 | A |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | B |
| 2 | 9 | 10 | A, B |
| 2 | 11 | 38 | A |

## Rough idea

My idea here is to:

1. I want to transform the table using `date` as a starting index for each personnel `id`
2. This way, we can transform the transformed `date` to `use` so that we obtain the relative ending date of uses as `start` + `use` - 1

   | `id` | `start` | `use` | `end` | `item` |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 90 | 90 | A |
   | 1 | 30 | 10 | 39 | B |
   | 1 | 44 | 15 | 58 | C |
   | 2 | 1 | 10 | 10 | B |
   | 2 | 9 | 30 | 38 | A |
3. Visually, the item acquisition journey for each personnel would be:

   Personnel 1:

   ```
                                                 +--------------C (15)  
                                  +---------B (10)  
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------A (90)  
   +------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------->  
   1                              30             44                                         90
   ```

   Personnel 2:

   ```
           +--------------------------------A (30)  
   +---------B (10)  
   +-------+-------------------------------->  
   1       9                              40
   ```
4. Finally, I can evaluate concurrent item acquisition as follow:

   | `id` | `start` | `end` | `item` |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 29 | A |
   | 1 | 30 | 39 | A, B |
   | 1 | 40 | 43 | A |
   | 1 | 44 | 58 | A, C |
   | 1 | 59 | 90 | A |
   | 2 | 1 | 8 | B |
   | 2 | 9 | 10 | A, B |
   | 2 | 11 | 38 | A |

## What I found

I found some relevant topics to this question, including:

- [What is a simple and efficient way to find rows with time-interval overlaps in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117962/what-is-a-simple-and-efficient-way-to-find-rows-with-time-interval-overlaps-in-s)
- [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

## What I tried

```sql
-- Create a dummy table
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id int,
  start_date date,
  day_of_use int,
  item varchar(8)
)
;

-- Populating table with sample data
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, "2023-02-01", 90, "A");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, "2023-03-02", 10, "B");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, "2023-03-15", 15, "C");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (2, "2023-02-05", 10, "B");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (2, "2023-02-13", 30, "A");

-- Querying the overlap
SELECT
  a.id,
  DATEDIFF(a.start_date, b.init) + 1 AS start,
  day_of_use,
  DATEDIFF(a.start_date, b.init) + day_of_use AS end,
  item
FROM
  tbl AS a
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT id, MIN(start_date) AS init
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY id
  ) AS b ON a.id = b.id
;
```

Though, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.. Any idea would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eB1GnZTuuH5P71kr4pWqHu/2

Comment: You could try unrolling your values with a recursive cte, then treat your problem as a gaps-and-islands and aggregate to gather your values [btw February 2023 doesn't have 29 days].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you could try:

- unrolling your values with a recursive cte
- treat your problem as a gaps-and-islands problem
- aggregate to gather your values

In order to address the gaps and islands problem, you may want to recreate your partitions using a running sum over the amount of items change in consecutive records.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, start_date AS date_, day_of_use, item
    FROM tbl
  
    UNION ALL 
  
    SELECT id, DATE_ADD(date_, INTERVAL 1 DAY), day_of_use-1, item  
    FROM cte
    WHERE day_of_use > 0
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT id, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_) AS rn, 
           item
    FROM cte
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT id, 
           rn,
           GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) AS items,
           LAG(GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item)) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS prev_items
    FROM cte2
    GROUP BY id, rn
), cte4 AS (
    SELECT id, rn, items,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN prev_items != items THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rn) AS parts
    FROM cte3 
)
SELECT id, MIN(rn) AS start_, MAX(rn) AS end_, items 
FROM cte4
GROUP BY id, items, parts
```

"**Output**":

| id | items | start_ | end_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 29 |
| 1 | A,B | 30 | 40 |
| 1 | A | 41 | 42 |
| 1 | A,C | 43 | 58 |
| 1 | A | 59 | 91 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | A,B | 9 | 11 |
| 2 | A | 12 | 39 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sLSpeYXaLu64Nv86TvEQv7/1).

Note that February 2023 doesn't have 29 days.

Comment: Thank you @lemon, seems like it suits my needs. However, when I query the database, it gives me an error stating "No order list in window specification for `lag`". I added the order list to query in cte3 as follow: `LAG(GROUP_CONCAT(item)) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rn)`. The fiddle works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sLSpeYXaLu64Nv86TvEQv7/4. Though, the server still gives me an error "Invalid use of group function". I'm not sure what's wrong with the query, might you have any idea?

Comment: You can try to split the aggregation and windowing into two separate ctes ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sLSpeYXaLu64Nv86TvEQv7/5)).

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna mark it as resolved, currently it works on my end